# How to disable only_full_group_by option in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, mysql-5.7

I am new to laravel and I am having an issue with DB problem.

I have disabled 'only_full_group_by' sql_mode by editing `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file. And I checked `sql_mode` for both global and session using `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` and `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` and confirmed that `sql_mode` no longer has `only_full_group_by`.

However, when I make a request through postman, it gives me the error saying `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.

I am so confused. Why do I get this error even after I changed `sql_mode`? Am I doing something wrong?

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**SQL using toSql()**

```
select A.* 
from `A` 
inner join `B` on `A`.`id` = `B`.`a_id` 
inner join `C` on `C`.`id` = `B`.`c_id` 
group by `A`.`id` having COUNT(A.id) > 0;
```

Comment: `SELECT *` is not compatible with `GROUP BY`. Before version 5.7.5, MySQL used to accept invalid `GROUP BY` queries but it reserved its right to return [indeterminate values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for the `SELECT` expressions that do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. The query can return different values using the same input on different machines. Disabling `only_full_group_by` doesn't solve the problem, it just hides it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong way of going about this.  Rather than turning off `only_full_group_by` mode, you should be fixing your query so that it doesn't break MySQL:

```
SELECT a1.*
FROM A a1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT A.id
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B
        ON A.id = B.a_id 
    INNER JOIN C
        ON C.id = B.c_id
    GROUP BY A.id
    HAVING COUNT(A.id) > 0
) a2
    ON a1.id = a2.id;
```

I don't know why your attempts to turn off strict mode failed, but you should not be relying on it in any case.

Comment: The correct answer to the specific question was provided by @Brian below. There are valid use cases where you don't want only_full_group_by set.  Especially when you want distinct values for a large dataset distinguished by one key.

Comment: @Dom Turning off strict mode is almost always a bad idea.  My answer offers a correct query which will run on MySQL is _any_ mode, and it would also probably run on most other databases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I completely disagree. Please read Dom DaFonte's answer and do some research.

Answer (score 26):

To answer the original question, if you want to disable this in Laravel you have to change the 'strict' value to *false* in your database configuration in config/database.php.

```
'connections' => [
...

    'mysql' => [
    ...
        'strict' => false,
        ...

    ],

]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to this question and resolved my issue.  I needed to group by one column, my my.cnf was configured properly, but I had to remove strict mode for laravel.  Really, if your database is properly configured with the strictness required, you don't need to have the application set to strict mode.

Comment: @Dom This answer does not reflect best SQL practice.  Grouping by one column while selecting all other columns is only valid if that one column happens to be a unique key.

Comment: This is the question that was posed, "How to disable only_full_group_by option in Laravel".  The answer to that question was provided by @Brian.  Although you did help him correct his sql, there are valid use cases to not have full_group_by set.  Otherwise, why would mysql allow one to remove this from the my.cnf.  This setting was only enabled on databases > 5.7.  You can of course offer the OP best practices with your response which is helpful, but the underlying goal of Stackoverflow is for a future reader to search for a question and find the answer to it.  And this is the correct answer.

Comment: Leaving strict=true should remain. @thebvg1ne-zoren provides the right answer,. I also added the full set of args. "sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1140-mixing-of-group-columns-minmaxcount-with-no-group-columns-is-illegal-if-there-is-no-group-by-clause

Answer (score 13):

In Laravel, you could do this on runtime instead of making a global setting

```
//disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
DB::statement("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));");

//Your SQL goes here - The one throwing the error (:

//re-enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
DB::statement("SET sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'));");
```

Comment: how can i make it global? Please tell me. Thanks

Comment: @Kamlesh View thebvg1ne-zoren's answer. It works. I added the full set "sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Comment: @blackmambo I am using Lumen 8. I have added this statement `DB::statement("SET sql_mode = '' ");` in constructor of every controller and it worked for me. BTW we can write this statement in global middleware also then we will not have to write this statement in every controller. Thanks a lot dear.

Comment: @Kamlesh You should never whip out the sql_mode config parameters. At the least, keep the basic set I mentioned above. Also, if you don't have access to the mysql config file, you should try to configure use your statement at the point when the connection to the database is configured.

Answer (score 3):

Add this modes to ***config/database.php***

```
'mysql' => [
 ...
        'modes' => [
            'STRICT_ALL_TABLES',
        ],
],
```

If you set
    `'strict' => true`. Some sql exception will not throw like sql data integrity exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable that on current mysql session

```
DB::statement("SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))");
```