# SQL mode only_full_group_by causing error in Lumen 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I have updated my lumen version from 5.6 to 5.7. In this illuminate/database package v5.7.15 enable MySQL mode only_full_group_by by default. This causes some of my Group By queries to fail. Most people suggests to disable strict mode in lumen. I think disable the strict mode is not a right solution. Is there any alternate query available in MySQL? Or I need to build a logic in PHP? I'm Using MySQL 5.6

I'm using quires like

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date_created) MONTH, YEAR(date_created) YEAR 
FROM test_table 
GROUP BY MONTH, YEAR
```

I'm not using aggregate functions. data_created column has datetime datatype

Comment: Review the queries and change them. without only_full_group_by you are likely to get incorrect or unexpected results. The usual solution is to add all columns from select clause into the group by clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable only\_full\_group\_by option in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145384/how-to-disable-only-full-group-by-option-in-laravel)

Comment: @SalmanA : I'm using quires like  SELECT MONTHNAME(date_created) MONTH, YEAR(date_created) YEAR FROM test_table GROUP BY MONTH, YEAR. I'm not using aggregate functions. data_created column has datetime datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that kind of query, where you don't use agregate functions that need GROUP BY, you can use distinct like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTHNAME(date_created) MONTH, YEAR(date_created) YEAR 
FROM test_table
```

So this way you don't need to disable the `full_group_by` restriction

Also you could do it this way:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date_created) MONTH, YEAR(date_created) YEAR 
FROM test_table 
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date_created), YEAR(date_created)
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query will fix the problem:

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

Answer (score 0):

If you working with MySQL 5.7 you should compensate full_group_by by changing your SQL query , or you can remove the full_group_by option from the mysq settings