# laravel query not working properly while working on sql database

Tags: sql, laravel

i run this query on phpmyadmin database table working fine:

```
select substring_index( prefix, '.', 3 ) as subip , count(prefix) as count, prefix 
from prefixes 
GROUP BY INET_ATON(subip)/256 
order by cidr desc
```

when i run raw query in laravel:

```
$selected_prefixes = DB::select("select substring_index( prefix, '.', 3 ) as subip , count(prefix) as count, prefix 
from prefixes 
GROUP BY INET_ATON(subip)/256 
order by cidr desc ");
```

giving this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
> 'portal.prefixes.prefix' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select
> substring_index( prefix, '.', 3 ) as subip , count(prefix) as count,
> prefix from prefixes GROUP BY INET_ATON(subip)/256 order by cidr desc
> )

here example table file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/vwnply7ggtai52m/prefixes(5).sql/file

Answer (score 1):

You can not retrieve the `prefix` column because some similar `subip` has different `prefixes`. I put the examples in the link below. You can check it out.

The following code works correctly.

```
select substring_index(prefix, '.', 3) as subip, count(*) as count 
from  prefixes
group by substring_index(prefix, '.', 3)
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c15e135510ddfac935d37e8531d830f)

Answer (score 0):

Doing select on columns that is not part of group by is in most SQL implementations not valid as the actual row that should be represented for that column could be any of the grouped rows.

I suspect you use MySQL which allows this with certain settings, in which case it will output a random value from the group (not necessarily the first).
When running through Laravel there must be other settings (more strict settings) in the database.php configuration.

You could loosen the strict settings in the database config, or you could rewrite the query, so that you dont select a column that is not part of the GROUP BY.

Comment: thanks for detail. but after enable strict mode can cause issue on live server.

Comment: You should change your query then. The problem is that the "prefix" column can contain different values for the returned row, as it is not part of the group by. You should either add the column to the GROUP BY or disable strict mode in laravel. Alternatively temporary disable the "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" sql mode as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145384/how-to-disable-only-full-group-by-option-in-laravel